# Reorder FlatList based on a value in the contents

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm passing data to my FlatList using the following code

```
<FlatList
  data={pubData}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Item
      id={item.id}
      name={item.name}
      lat={item.lat}
      long={item.long}
      deviceLat={deviceLat}
      deviceLong={deviceLong}
    />
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
/>
```

In the Item component, I'm running some code to check the distance between the lat longs to create a list of items and their distance from the location of the device. This all works great, however, I'm confused on how to sort this list after the distances are generated.

Comment: Why do the calculation at item level ?, try to do it at parent component level and update the data in the state which will rerender only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rule of thumb is, Try to avoid calculations inside the list(ListItems) since these calculations will be done in every item so FlatList will start causing performance issues if calculations are too much.

The second thing is, Always provide your `Final data to the FlatList`, I had to face a similar situation where I was doing all the calculations inside the ListItem and I face performance issues than I moved my all of the calculations in FlatList Container and this work well, I don't know your implementation and requirement but keep In mind these things while working with Lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort Data Source State and  re-render FlatList, but it's better to do all calculations before rendering data.